# Deploy the same Azure binaries to multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, deployment, web-config, devops

We are trying to work out a good continuous deployment setup using TFS, Visual Studio and Azure. At our company, each developer has their own Azure subscription that we use for testing, as well as shared QA1/QA2/PROD subscriptions that we can deploy to. We have matching TFS XAML build definitions for each of these, running Powershell scripts with parameters and PublishSettings files.

This all gives us a set of .cspkg and .cspkg files, and in theory we can deploy the right cspkg with the correct cspkg to any Azure system.

The problem we are encountering now though is that we want to start using the Redis Cache service. Installing the nuget package writes subscription-specific settings into the web.config, to point at the cache. This means that the cspkg is now complied specifically for the Azure subscription.

We could use SlowCheetah to merge web.config files on build, but this means that we would have to compile the package for each build definition, and as the number of developers increases this is obviously going to become unsustainable.

I am looking for a way to keep our old generic packages and still use the Redis Cache. We can connect to the cache in code during app_start, but then we can't use it to store IIS session state. I understand that the Azure Load Balancer is meant to keep users on the same server, but I'm unsure how that will work as we swap servers in/out.

It feels like we are approaching the problem wrong and there should be a simple solution that we are overlooking.

We are using Azure Tools 2.6, Visual Studio 2013, TFS 2015r2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are always 3 ways of doing this.

1st one is config during build, which is building one thing for one thing you described, which is not desired in most of scenario.

2nd is config during deployment, which means you open the cspkg file, change config, then put it back before upload without re-compile.

3nd is config after deployment, have a configuration management tool adjust the config file for you on the fly.

We use [octopus deploy](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Deploying+a+package+to+an+Azure+Cloud+Service) to archive #2 above, our CI tool feed octopus with cspkg and cscfg, octopus handles the rest. I would definitely not going after #1 but consider #3 is a valid option too.

Answer (score 0):

As of today we store all our connection settings in .cscfg files. Even if for security reasons, we avoid storing any production connection strings in source control, only QA. And we have CI for QA, but not production. This way it works well for us, we just maintain different .cscfg for different environments (subscriptions)

However, in near future I think we will move to Key Vault for this.